# mySQL Foreign Key Constraint Not Being Saved When Updated Through Workbench

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

Whenever I update the foreign key constraint setting through mySQL workbench, the updated setting isn't saved permanently.

Despite setting the foreign key option to null and successfully saving the changes, upon reopening the alter table tab it will revert back to showing restrict. What am I doing wrongly?
[image]

Comment: Do `show create table nric;` to see what is actually there, rather than relying on a client like workbench that makes it difficult to see

Answer (score 0):

The updated settings to the foreign key constraints have actually already been applied just that it isn't showing on the mySQL workbench UI.

By checking the update_rule and delete_rule on mySQL, the constraints have indeed be updated to be of null action.
[image]

```
   SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME,
           UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
           MATCH_OPTION, 
           UPDATE_RULE,
           DELETE_RULE,
           TABLE_NAME,
           REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
    WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'node_express_mysql';
```